# How to get the total number of records processed by Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark

Does anyone know how does Spark compute its number of records (I think it is the same as the number of events in a batch), as displayed here?

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how I can get this value remotely (REST-API does not exist for Streaming option in the UI).

Basically what I'm trying to do it to get the total number of records processed by my application. I need this information for the web portal.

I tried to count the `Records` for each stage, but it gave me completely different number as it is at the picture above. Each stage contain the infomation about its records. As shown here

[image]

I'm using this short python script to count the "inputRecords", from each stage. This is the source code:

```
import json, requests, urllib
print "Get stages script started!"
#URL REST-API
url = 'http://10.16.31.211:4040/api/v1/applications/app-20161104125052-0052/stages/'
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

stages = []
print len(data)
inputCounter = 0
for item in data:
        stages.append(item["stageId"])
        inputCounter += item["inputRecords"]
print "Records processed: " + str(inputCounter)
```

If I understood it correctly: Each `Batch` has one `Job`, and each `Job` has multiple `Stages`, these `Stages` have multiple `Tasks`.

So for me it made sense to count the input for each `Stage`.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some sample data and code, and tell us what isn't working for you. Also, check this link out: stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Maybe the question should be "How to get the total number of records processed by Spark Streaming"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spark offers a metrics endpoint on the driver:

```
<driver-host>:<ui-port>/metrics/json
```

A Spark Streaming application will report all metrics available in the UI and some more.  The ones you are potentially looking for are:

```
<driver-id>.driver.<job-id>.StreamingMetrics.streaming.totalProcessedRecords: {
value: 48574640
},
<driver-id>.driver.<job-id>.StreamingMetrics.streaming.totalReceivedRecords: {
value: 48574640
}
```

This endpoint can be customized. See [Spark Metrics](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#metrics) for info.

Comment: Thank you! It really works, this /metrics/json option was hidden to me.

Comment: @SeverinSimko is not a well known feature. BTW, if you consider your question answered, don't forget to accept it. Also consider changing the title so that  future visitors can also benefit... and welcome to SO!