# How to fetch the number of processed and unprocessed data from spark using python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I want to fetch the number of Processed and unprocessed data from Apache Spark using python. I have referred to different online materials but wasn't able to understand the solution.

Links of solution referred: - 
http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Registering-custom-metrics-td9030.html#a9968

[How to get the total number of records processed by Spark Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421368/how-to-get-the-total-number-of-records-processed-by-spark-streaming)

This is what I have as an output. I want to fetch Processed and unprocessed data from this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MMCO.png)

Comment: Hello @Manan, welcome to stackoverflow. Please explain us what you tried, what you want and what went wrong proving minimum reproducable input sample. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello @Gladiator, I have attached an image of the output which I am getting and I want to fetch the number of Processed and unprocessed data from this.